# Fluent Bit does not send logs from my EKS custom applications

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am using AWS Opensearch to retrieve the logs from all my Kubernetes applications.
I have the following pods: `Kube-proxy`, `Fluent-bit`, `aws-node`, `aws-load-balancer-controller`, and all my apps (around 10).

While fluent-bit successfully send all the logs from `Kube-proxy`, `Fluent-bit`, `aws-node` and `aws-load-balancer-controller`, none of the logs from my applications are sent. My applications had `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `ERROR` logs, and none are sent by fluent bit.

Here is my fluent bit configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-config
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluent-bit
data:
  # Configuration files: server, input, filters and output
  # ======================================================
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            my-host.es.amazonaws.com
        Port            443
        TLS             On
        AWS_Auth        On
        AWS_Region      ap-southeast-1
        Retry_Limit     6

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name   apache
        Format regex
        Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

    [PARSER]
        Name   apache2
        Format regex
        Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

    [PARSER]
        Name   apache_error
        Format regex
        Regex  ^\[[^ ]* (?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\](?: \[pid (?<pid>[^\]]*)\])?( \[client (?<client>[^\]]*)\])? (?<message>.*)$

    [PARSER]
        Name   nginx
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

    [PARSER]
        Name   json
        Format json
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep   On

    [PARSER]
        Name        syslog
        Format      regex
        Regex       ^\<(?<pri>[0-9]+)\>(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %b %d %H:%M:%S
```

I followed [this documentation](https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/230_logging/deploy/)

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I did two things that solved my issue:

1. Modified this configuration:

```
# before
 output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            search-blacaz-logs-szzq6vokwwm4y5fkfwyngjwjxq.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com
        Port            443
        TLS             On
        AWS_Auth        On
        AWS_Region      ap-southeast-1
        Retry_Limit     6

# after
 output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            search-blacaz-logs-szzq6vokwwm4y5fkfwyngjwjxq.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com
        Port            443
        TLS             On
        AWS_Auth        On
        Replace_Dots    On // added this
        AWS_Region      ap-southeast-1
        Retry_Limit     6
```

Then, I had to delete the fluent-bit Elastic search index, and re-create it.
Indeed, the index was probably not well suited for my JAVA logs at first, and adjusted to it after re-creation.

Answer (score -1):

have you seen [this article](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#concepts) from official side? Pay attention on [Log files overview](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#log-files-overview) section.

> When deploying Fluent Bit to Kubernetes, there are three log files that you need to pay attention to.
> C:\k\kubelet.err.log

Also you can find [Fluent GitHub Community](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging) and create an issue there to have better support from its contributors

There is a [Slack channel](http://slack.fluentd.org/) for Fluent